# How I can rename the contents of compressed file befor extract in python?

Tags: python, zip

Is there is a way to rename the file name inside the compressed file ,but without extract it,  in python ??

Answer (score 0):

No.  The python ZipFile module does not provide any way to do that.
You can extract the archive into memory, and then rewrite it with the new filename for the file in question, but that is memory intensive and not what you want to do.
You may be able to edit the zipfile's header and information fields, but the standard Python interface doesn't have an easy way to do so.